# Convert HTML to PDF Using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I currently have a page that generates HTML and fills in fields based on `$_GET` values from the previous PHP page.

I would like to convert the HTML of the page that I am on to a PDF and load it.

Can anybody help me out?

For some reason I get this as an error on page load:

> Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 2
>
> Warning:
>   require_once(http://kenai.asap.um.maine.edu/asapweb/libs/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php):
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error:
>   require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'http://kenai.asap.um.maine.edu/asapweb/libs/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 2

My page:

```
<?php
require_once("http://kenai.asap.um.maine.edu/asapweb/libs/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
ob_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;">
        <h2><center>ASAP APPLICATION FORM</center></h2>
        <hr style="width: 700px;"><br>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 15%;">Date Submitted: <b><?php echo $_GET['dateSubmitted'] ?></b><br>
            <div style="margin-top: 50px;"><h3><i>PERSONAL INFORMATION</i></h3></div><br>

            <div style="margin-left: 50px">
                Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['firstName']." ".$_GET['lastName'] ?></u></b><br>
                Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['address'] ?></u></b><br>
                Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['phone'] ?></u></b><br>
                Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['email'] ?></u></b><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 150px; margin-top: 50px;"><h3><i>ACADEMIC INFORMATION</i></h3><br>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 50px;">
                Major:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['major'] ?></u></b><br>
                Expected Graduation Year:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['gradDate'] ?></u></b><br>
                Relevant work?:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo ucfirst($_GET['work']) ?></u></b><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top: 250px; margin-left: 39%;"><h3><i>TELL US MORE ABOUT YOU</i></h3><br>

            <div style="margin-left: -200px; margin-top: 20px;"><b>Position(s) interested in:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_GET['positions'] ?></div>
            <br>
            <div style="margin-left: -200px; margin-bottom: 50px;"><b>Do you have work-study?</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_GET['workStudy'] ?></div>

            <div style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 70px;">Describe your creative strengths:</span><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="40" style="margin-top: 20px;"><?php echo $_GET['previousExperience'] ?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: -240px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 30px;">Briefly describe your previous work experience:</span><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="40" style="margin-top: 20px;"><?php echo $_GET['creativeStrengths'] ?></textarea>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 100px;">What are your skills?:</span><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="40" style="margin-top: 20px;"><?php echo $_GET['skills'] ?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: -240px;">
                <span style="margin-left: 50px;">What interests you about this position?:</span><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="40" style="margin-top: 20px;"><?php echo $_GET['interests'] ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the warning is pretty clear: you're trying to access a file that doesn't exist; check whether you have write access to where it should get created, and that you match filename case exactly (OSX/Windows notirously don't, unix production servers really, really do)

Comment: Updated error, I had the wrong folder name.

Comment: Sorry, updated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `require` and `include` files using the local server path, **not** the external HTTP path. (unless you have [`allow_url_include`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) set to `true`)

Change this line

```
 require_once("http://kenai.asap.um.maine.edu/asapweb/libs/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

to

```
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/asapweb/libs/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

This is assuming the path is correct from your server's docroot.

Comment: `Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/asapweb/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 3 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/asapweb/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 3`

Comment: If i follow the path in FileZilla it is correct however.

Comment: @Nicolas Make a new file and run this PHP code: `var_dump(scandir('/var/www/html/asapweb/dompdf'))`

What is the output?

Comment: Warning: scandir(/var/www/html/asapweb/dompdf): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 3 Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/asapweb/libs/full.php on line 3 bool(false)

Comment: @Nicolas What does `var_dump(scandir('/var/www/html'))` return? Give it to me in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Nicolas and finally, `var_dump(scandir('/var/www/html/asapweb'))`? Do you know where I'm going with this?

Comment: array(9) { [0]=> string(1) "." [1]=> string(2) ".." [2]=> string(16) "asap-application" [3]=> string(3) "css" [4]=> string(9) "documents" [5]=> string(9) "index.php" [6]=> string(4) "libs" [7]=> string(12) "settings.php" [8]=> string(9) "templates" } Sort of? I'm confused because my path looks accurate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59217/discussion-between-sjagr-and-nicolas).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
include("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

Assuming that your dompdf_config.inc.php is available in following path.

```
/var/www/html/asapweb/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php
```